# Using the Singleton pattern with an interface in C#

Tags: c#, static, singleton

Note: Even though there are a lot of similar questions, non that i have found answered my question.

Problem:
I would like to implement a class in C# which uses the singleton pattern in the following way.

```
namespace DAL
{
    public class CDAL : IDAL
    {
        /* Singleton Pattern */
        private CDAL instance = null;
        private CDAL()
        {
        }
        public IDAL getInstance()
        {
            if (instance != null)
            {
                return instance;
            }
            else
            {
                CDAL.instance = new CDAL();
                return CDAL.instance;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

the problem is that **instance** and the method **getInstance** should be **static**, as i want to 'ask' the class for that instance and not an object.
but using c# i can't seem to do anything static in an interface.

how can i solve this?

Comment: Why would you want a singleton to implement an interface in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not make any sense creating an interface with a static member. 
Interfaces are a contract while the static member is always accessed by the class name, not the instance name. so briefly your interface does not know  which the correct instance implementing the right logic. 
in your case you don't need your method `getInstance()` to be defined in  the interface.
Interface when  used with  `Singleton` is often just for `unit testing` purposes

Answer (score 4):

You're right, you cannot do anything static on an interface, since it does not make any sense.
Use an abstract class instead of the interface to implement static logic.

Comment: Since static methods can't be overriden, I'd opt for a separate static factory rather than inheritance. It'd work the exact same way and be less confusing.